# Populating the group data of array in laravel blade

Tags: arrays, laravel

I have array like that, I want to populate it in laravel blade using foreach loop.
Here is my query:-

```
$data['cities'] = Shop::groupBy('area')->select('area', 'city')->get()->groupBy('city')->toarray();
```

Array
(
    [rawalpindi] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [area] => 6 road
                    [city] => rawalpindi
                )

```
        [1] => Array
            (
                [area] => khan bakeri
                [city] => rawalpindi
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [area] => stadium road
                [city] => rawalpindi
            )

    )

[islamabad] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [area] => i9 markaz
                [city] => islamabad
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [area] => Street 111
                [city] => islamabad
            )

    )
```

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show it in blade like this:

```
@foreach($cities as $city => $areas)
  <h1>{{ $city }}</h1>
  @foreach($areas as $area)
    {{ $area['area'] }} <br>
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks Its working fine..
But if we want to populate it in javascript?